# .Net Tcp/ip data reception

Tags: .net, tcp

I wrote a chunck of code in order to listen to remote clients via tcp/ip protocole.
i was able to recieve data from clients . but i have no idea how to knwo if the client stop sending data to finish the connection.
this is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 34400);
            TcpClient client;
            listener.Start();

            while (true) // Add your exit flag here
            {
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, client);
            }
        }

        private static void ThreadProc(object state)
        {
            string imei = string.Empty;
            var client = ((TcpClient) state);
            NetworkStream nwStream = ((TcpClient) state).GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

            try
            {


                while (true)
                {
                    int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

                    string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    if (imei == string.Empty)
                    {
                        imei = dataReceived;
                        Console.WriteLine("IMEI received : " + dataReceived);

                        Byte[] b = { 0x01 };
                        nwStream.Write(b, 0, 1);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int dataNumber =  Convert.ToInt32(buffer.Skip(9).Take(1).ToList()[0]); ;

                        var result = 0;
                        while (dataNumber > 0)
                        {
                            var parser = new TeltonikaDevicesParser(false);
                            result = parser.Decode(new List<byte>(buffer), imei);
                            dataNumber--;
                        }
                        nwStream.Write(
                            result > 0 ? new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 } : new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, 0,
                            4);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: it's a good question I can only think of two ways off hand: 1) a message exchanged that exits and 2) is an idle timeout exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. TCP/IP does not care much about closing a connection on one end. The state of disconnection turns out only when you try to send data through.

You have to implement a simple protocol over TCP/IP to complete your code:

- Know in advance how much data you expect. An IMEI number has a set length.
- Wait until the transfer times out. What ever you received is yours.
- Send over first how much data you intend to transfer and when you got all of them your job is done.